# Time goes wrong after some houres of setInverval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datetime, time, setinterval

I implemented a very basic digital Clock in JavaScript to display the time on a TV. After some hours of displaying it seems that the time goes some seconds (like 30 or more) wrong.

Here is my code:

```
  getTime() {

    const time = new Date();

    const formatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-AT', {
        hour: "2-digit",
        minute: "2-digit"
    });

    return formatter.format(time);
  }

  updateClock() {
    this.clock = this.getTime();
  }
```

which gets called in an setIntervall():

```
 setInterval(() => {
      this.updateClock();
    }, 1000);
```

I don't get, why the time goes wrong after some hours of executing. I would understand, if I just add some time, but since I instancate a new Date-Object everytime, I think it should work properly.

**EDIT:**
JavaScript was not the problem. The issue is caused by the internal clock of the TV, which gets out of sync over time (for whatever reason). Since, get DateTime() seems to rely on the system time of the TV, which is wrong, the clock is also wrong.

Comment: The use of `setInterval` is never recommended. You should periodically call `setTimeout` and grab the actual time. These methods can get out of sync easily, since they are based on your system's performance. If these processes are stalled, you will keep losing time.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl This is an exaggeration. It's certainly recommended where it's suitable. Like in this case. It would be a problem if time were incremented on interval but here it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Timers are not meant to execute *exactly* when you schedule them, there could be delays around but in general, `setInterval` with a second delay easily messes up on ticking seconds.

If you have more than seconds messing up there could be too many intervals around, and your code doesn't indeed store a possible `clearInterval` value anywhere, but the long story short is that you can reduce the interval, if it's granted to be executed only once, and be done with it ... if the browser decides to not call it anymore, it will catch up once you focus the main window again.

Use a `1000 / 60` delay instead (60 FPS) and see if that improves, if it doesn't, it means your TV/browser decided to not trigger that interval until you wake it up again, which is expected by specs.

Comment: Off course. But I thought it doesnt matter, that it dont execute exactly, since i should always get the proper time from new Date(). So does the Date Object get messed up?

Comment: if we're talking seconds ticks, they go off with ease ... if we're talking time stuck in time, the explanation is that browsers arbitrarily decide when to stop executing intervals (thnk about them pausing the WebView and its JS engine)

Comment: The TV is always awake (it's a display for a store). But even the Interval would stop, the time should be correct on resumeing the interval - or do I not get something here?

Comment: @JohannesReiter—you're correct in thinking that because a new *Date* is created each time it should show the correct time. It may be a second or so late to change the values from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you store the result of `setInterval` (the interval id), so that you can start and stop the interval.

Since you are getting the current time, every second, the time *should* be correct at the time it is formatted.

Here is a modified example using a class:

```js
class Clock {
  constructor({ formatter, renderer }) {
    this.formatter = formatter;
    this.renderer = renderer;
    this.time = '';
  }
  update() {
    this.time = this.formatter.format(new Date());
    if (this.renderer instanceof Function) {
      this.renderer(this);
    }
  }
  start() {
    if (this.intervalId) {
      clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    }
    this.update(); // Call it initially
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.update(); // Call it every second
    }, 1000);
  }
  stop() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    this.intervalId = undefined;
  }
}

const clockEl = document.querySelector('#clock');

const clock = new Clock({
  formatter: Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-AT', {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
  }),
  renderer: (clockRef) => {
    clockEl.innerText = clockRef.time;
  }
});
clock.start();
```

```html
<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Stopping though, is in that use case not necessary. 
The strange behaviour is, that the time **is not** correct after some time. So I was wondering, how the date object could get messed up.